# php error_log not working in local environment

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm running copy of PHP as a local server under Windows 10.
[image]

I have got a simple test script "t.php":

```
error_log('one');
ini_set('error_log', 'ttt.log');        // may be also absolute path like c:\ttt.log - does not work either 
error_log('two');
echo 't';
```

After running that script the second message is sent "to nowhere" - there is no file with the message 'two'.

[image]

Any help, how to get the second message in error_log file?

Comment: Does the file exist? Is it writable? Have you tried something like `error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: The file does not exists (that's what I wish - the file to be created). I've tried error_log('...', 3, '...') - it does not work either

Comment: And of course I know the PHP manual. The question is rather about local environment than general error handling.I have got quite complicated PHP systems running on the web and there is no problem with managing errors.

Comment: Use the complete path in `ini_set` and make sure that the folder is writable/the file can be created. Just tried without problems, a new file gets created. Using a relative path in `error_log("You messed up!", 3, "./errors.log");` also works. Check your folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what's been wrong. The problem was caused by Windows 10 file security system, not PHP itself. Oryginally I started PHP program from .BAT file. PHP had no permission to write to any file, so all attempts to write a log file were silently discarded by Windows. After running PHP from .LNK file (shortcut to original file) and assigning administrator privileges in that file - the problem disappeared.